# How in yii2 output in url instead of mysite / product / id => mysite / product / title?

Tags: php, yii2

I have such a problem, I want on my site to display all the id of the product, its title in view

Here is an example - http: // localhost / yii-application / product / 1

Comes into product view with id = 1

And I want it to be so -
http: // localhost / yii-application / product / TestTitle

and went so in the view of the product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your action parameter and urlmanager in config file . Normally In view action we'll pass **id** as a parameter and using Id we'll get product information. Now we are changing instead of Id we are getting **product information** through **Title** of the product.

## frontend/controllers/ProductController.php:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{

     public function actionView($title)
     {
        //Based on title getting product information
        $productData = ProductModel::find ()->where(['title'=>$title])->asArray()->one();

        return $this->render('view',
          [
              'productData'=>$productData,
          ]);
     }
}
```

## frontend/views/product/view.php:

```
your html code for display product view
```

## frontend/config/main.php

Here we are passing title as a parameter for view acton

```
'urlManager' => [
  'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
  'showScriptName' => false,
  'rules' => [
    'product/view/<title:\w+>'=>'product/view',
    -------------------------------------------
    -------------------------------------------
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/' => '<controller>/<action>',
  ]
]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is far more complicated in practice, because title needs to be unique in this case, and URLs will look like crap if it will contain non-latin characters. It is better to use slug approach or with combined ID and simplified title as suffix.

Comment: @rob006 : Yes, you are right, if we are using slug it will be good, in product info anyway we need maintain slug. In that case instead of title we can slug

Comment: If two products have the same title, how does one produce?

Comment: for that reason we need to implement slug behavior , it will append extra numerical to existing slug , e.g test-title,test-title1...etc